# Cannot install g++ on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I don't have g++:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ which g++
erelsgl@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ 

erelsgl@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ g++
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So I try to install it:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~/srilm$ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up g++ (4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/g++ doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing g++ (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of build-essential:
 build-essential depends on g++ (>= 4:4.3.1); however:
  Package g++ is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing build-essential (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 g++
 build-essential
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also try to install build-essential, and get same results.

I also tried "sudo apt-get update" - didn't help.

This is my apt-cache:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ apt-cache policy g++ build-essential
g++:
  Installed: 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
build-essential:
  Installed: 11.4build1
  Candidate: 11.4build1
  Version table:
 *** 11.4build1 0
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
erelsgl@ubuntu:/etc/apt$
```

I also tried this and got the same error:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~/Ace/Files/corpus$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up g++ (4:4.4.3-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/g++ doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing g++ (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of build-essential:
 build-essential depends on g++ (>= 4:4.3.1); however:
  Package g++ is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing build-essential (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 g++
 build-essential
```

Comment: Looks like you're running Ubuntu Lucid. Could you add the output of `apt-cache policy g++ build-essential`?

Comment: You are right! I added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to this and other similar problems in my Ubuntu 10.04, so finally I upgraded to 12.04 and now everything works fine... Sometimes, the package system gets confused, so the best solution is just to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is a problem with your current g++ installation. First remove it:

Get your installed g++ package: `dpkg --list 'g++'`

Remove it: `dpkg --purge g++XXXX`

Then install it again: `apt-get install g++`

Going to the package with `synaptic` (gui) or `aptitude` (command-line) might also give more information about the status of the package.

Comment: This sounds promising, however I cannot figure out the output:
erelsgl@ubuntu:~/Ace/Files/corpus$ sudo dpkg --list 'g++'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
iF  g++            4:4.4.3-1ubunt The GNU C++ compiler

Comment: It seems I have version 4.4.3, but I cannot remove it:
erelsgl@ubuntu:~/Ace/Files/corpus$ sudo dpkg --purge 'g++4.4.3'
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove g++4.4.3 which isn't installed.

I also tried 'g++-4.4.3', 'g++4.4.3-1ubunt', 'g++4.4.3-1ubuntu' 'g++-4.4.3-1ubunt', 'g++-4.4.3-1ubuntu' - I probably miss the correct variant

Comment: try just "dpkg --purge g++"

Comment: OK, the purge worked, but the install still gives the same error...

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like g++ is half-installed.  Try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same error - see my latest edit above.